# Uniformly continuity on a domain, $D$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let the $f : D(\subset \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$

To show the $f$ is  Uniformly continuous on $D$, It is false method that $f$ is a uniformly continuous on any interval of the $D$. Instead, Considering the $D = D_1 \cup D_2$, Is it enough to show the $f$ is a uniformly continuous on $D$ by showing the $f$ is a Uniformly continuous on each $D_1$ and $D_2$?

In short, my question is the below statement does hold or not.

$f$ is  Uniformly continuous on $D$ $\iff$ $f$ is  Uniformly continuous on both $D_1$ and $D_2$

(Here the $D = D_1 \cup D_2$)

Surely the direction "$\Rightarrow$" is true. But what about the opposite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not correct. For example, let $f(x)=-1$ for $x\in [-1,0]=:D_1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (0,1]=:D_2$
Then $f$ is uniformly continuous -actually even Lipschitz- in both $D_1$ and $D_2$. But $f$ is not even continuous on $[-1,1]$, let alone uniformly continuous.